# PHP: letting your own function work with a while loop

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop

$qVraagGroepenOp = "SELECT * FROM $tabele WHERE $where";
    $rVraagGroepenOp = mysql_query ( $qVraagGroepenOp );
    $aVraagGroepenOp = mysql_fetch_assoc ( $rVraagGroepenOp )

and I converted that to a function

```
vraagOp("testtable","testtable_ID = $id");

function vraagOp($table,$where)
{
    $qVraagOp = "SELECT * FROM $table WHERE $where";
    $rVraagOp = mysql_query( $qVraagOp );
    $aVraagOp = mysql_fetch_assoc( $rVraagOp );

    return $aVraagOp;
}
```

only the problem is when i need more then one row i need to use a while loop

```
$qVraagGroepenOp = "SELECT * FROM testtable where testtype = test";
$rVraagGroepenOp = mysql_query ( $qVraagGroepenOp );
while ( $aVraagGroepenOp = mysql_fetch_assoc ( $rVraagGroepenOp ) ) 
{
     echo "testing <br>";
}
```

It wont work anymore is there a trick to make my function work with this while loop?

This **won't** work but I want to reach to something like it

```
while (vraagOp("testtable","testtype = test")) 
{
   echo "testing <br>";
}
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Why are you using such unreadable variables?  Just KISS and call them $query, $result and $row  like everybody else.

Comment: @TravisO: Wow. They are _clearly_ another language, Dutch to be precise. And they are quite simple for him.

Comment: Fine, then he should be using $query $antwoord $rij I don't care what language he's using, his formatting is needlessly verbose and prefixing a single letter to separate query from result from row is silly.  Less is more.

Answer (score 3):

This could be done with static variables in the function scope.

```
function vraagOp($table,$where)
{
    static $rVraagOp;
    if(!$rVraagOp){
        $qVraagOp = "SELECT * FROM $table WHERE $where";
        $rVraagOp = mysql_query( $qVraagOp );
    }
    return mysql_fetch_assoc( $rVraagOp );
}
```

That should do what you're after.

Comment: hhm doesnt seem to work maybe the idea is rigth but it gives errors:


Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in D:\webuilding\wamp\www\onderzoeks-manager\functions\ev\sqlFunctions.php on line 10

probarly because the request has never been exucuted

Comment: @matthy: You're right, sorry about that.  I had made $qVraagOp when I should have made $rVraagOp static.  You could try this sample, and see if it works.

Comment: its a nice trick however it wont let you call the functio more then once the 2nd time you call the function it wont do anything because it wont get in the if if(!$rVraagOp){} loop any tip to let that work it almost works perfectly exept for this thing ;)

Answer (score 2):

This function returns an array of rows - it's a generic pattern yu can use almost anywhere you get multiple rows from a query.

```
function vraagOp($table,$where)
{
    $sql= "SELECT * FROM $table WHERE $where";
    $query= mysql_query($sql);
    if ($query != false)
    {
        $result = array(); 
        while ( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query) )
            $result[] = $row;
        return $result;
    }

    return $false;
}
//usage
$rows = vraagOp($table,$where);
if ($rows)
{
    foreach ($rows as $row)
        use($row);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This function will 'cache' the mysql result resource from each unique $table/$where combination, and fetch the next result from it on each subsequent call.  It will return an associative array for each row, or `false` when there are no rows left.

```
function vraagOp($table, $where)
{
    // Holds our mysql resources in a map of "{$table}_{$where}" => resource
    static $results = array();

    $key = $table . '_' . $where;

    if (!isset($results[$key]))
    {
      // first call of this particular table/where
      $results[$key] = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $table WHERE $where");
    }

    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($results[$key]);

    if ($row === false)
      // remove this key so a subsequent call will start over with a new query
      unset($results[$key]);

    return $row;
}

// Usage

while ($row = vraagOp("table1", "where field > 7")) {
   print_r($row);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This

```
while (vraagOp("testtable","testtype = test")) 
{
   echo "testing <br>";
}
```

will work if you change VraagOp() to return `false` when no matching record was found.

You would have to move the `mysql_query()` part out of VraagOp(), and just leave the `mysql_fetch_assoc` part in.

However, I can't really see what benefit there would be? You would just be building a (unnecessary) wrapper around `mysql_fetch_assoc()`, wouldn't you?

Comment: well this now is 3 lines shorter and easyer to renember to type.
i only have to type vraagop in stead op the whole code

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to turn `vraagOp()` into an [iterator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.iterator.php) and then use `foreach()` in order to make this work.

Comment: yes thougth of that but using an foreach isnt making the code easyer

Comment: The `foreach()` isn't the part that does all the work. It's only needed to make the rest run.

Answer (score 0):

Your example won’t work because the condition is executed on every iteration. That means `vraagOp("testtable","testtype = test")` would be called with each iteration until it returns a falsely value. `mysql_fetch_assoc` does that but your function doesn’t.

Answer (score 0):

How can we call function inside while loop example is below :

```
$sql_gpfsF="SELECT * FROM emp_salary";


$result_gpfsF=mysql_query($sql_gpfsF);

while($row_gpfsF=mysql_fetch_assoc($result_gpfsF))
{

call_function();    

}

function call_function()
{

echo " Function Called </ br>";

}
```

Comment: How is your answer better than those 6 already posted long time ago?